# Is it possible to order the execution of Subversion/svn commit hooks?

Tags: svn

I have a script `b` that I want to run after script `a`. I would have just combined the two into one script, but script `a` is supposed to run for all repos, and `b` is just for one or two repos. Is there a way to order the execution of svn commit hooks?

Answer (score 0):

You could call `b` from `a` if the repository is within your desired set.